# How to retrieve rows matching a criteria from the multi dimensional numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a multidimensional NumPy array read from a CSV file. I want to retrieve rows matching a certain column in the data set dynamically.

My current array is

```
[[LIMS_AY60_51X, AY60_51X_61536153d7cdc55.png, 857.61389, 291.227, NO, 728.322,865.442]
[LIMS_AY60_52X, AY60_52X_615f6r53d7cdc55.png, 867.61389, 292.227, NO, 728.322,865.442]
[LIMS_AY60_53X, AY60_53X_615ft153d7cdc55.png, 877.61389, 293.227, NO, 728.322,865.442]
[LIMS_AY60_54X, AY60_54X_615u6153d7cdc55.png, 818.61389, 294.227, NO, 728.322,865.442]
[LIMS_AY60_55X, AY60_55X_615f615od7cdc55.png, 847.61389, 295.227, NO, 728.322,865.442]......]
```

I would like to use 'np.where' method to extract the rows matching the criteria as follows :
(second column value equal to

> 'AY60_52X_615f6r53d7cdc55.png'

```
np.where ((vals == (:,'AY60_52X_615f6r53d7cdc55.png',:,:,:,:,:)).all(axis=1))
```

This one has an error due to syntax.

```
File "<ipython-input-31-a28fe9729cd4>", line 3
    np.where ((vals == (:,'AY60_52X_615f6r53d7cdc55.png',:,:,:,:,:)).all(axis=1))
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: As a side note: perhaps you could use Pandas? It will probably make things easier when processing CSV data. In particular your problem is incredibly straightforward in Pandas.

Comment: I am new to Python and using NumPy in most cases. I use Pandas only for data visualization. But I could try this

Comment: Data visualization is Matplotlib and Seaborn. The latter plays nice with Pandas, but as I mentioned, dealing with CSV like data (that is, tables), is generally (a lot) easier done with Pandas. Read through some parts of [the user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html) to get a feel what can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dealing with CSV files and tabular data handling, I'd recommend using Pandas.

Here's very briefly how that would work in your case (`df` is the usual variable name for a Pandas **D**ata**F**rame, hence `df`).

```
df = pd.read_csv('datafile.csv')
print(df)
```

results in the output

```
            code                      filename     value1   value2 yesno  anothervalue  yetanothervalue
0  LIMS_AY60_51X  AY60_51X_61536153d7cdc55.png  857.61389  291.227    NO       728.322          865.442
1  LIMS_AY60_52X  AY60_52X_615f6r53d7cdc55.png  867.61389  292.227    NO       728.322          865.442
2  LIMS_AY60_53X  AY60_53X_615ft153d7cdc55.png  877.61389  293.227    NO       728.322          865.442
3  LIMS_AY60_54X  AY60_54X_615u6153d7cdc55.png  818.61389  294.227    NO       728.322          865.442
4  LIMS_AY60_55X  AY60_55X_615f615od7cdc55.png  847.61389  295.227    NO       728.322          865.442
```

Note that the very first column is called the index. It is not in the CSV file, but automatically added by Pandas. You can ignore it here.
The column names are thought-up by me; usually, the first row of the CSV file will have column names, and otherwise Pandas will default to naming them something like "Unnamed: 0", "Unnamed: 1", "Unnamed: 2" etc.

Then, for the actual selection, you do

```
df['filename'] == 'AY60_52X_615f6r53d7cdc55.png'
```

which results in

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: filename, dtype: bool
```

which is a one-dimensional dataframe, called a Series. Again, it has an index column, but more importantly, the second column shows for which row the comparison is true.

You can assign the result to a variable instead, and use that variable to access the rows that have `True`, as follows:

```
selection = df['filename'] == 'AY60_52X_615f6r53d7cdc55.png'
print(df[selection])
```

which yields

```
            code                      filename     value1   value2 yesno  anothervalue  yetanothervalue
1  LIMS_AY60_52X  AY60_52X_615f6r53d7cdc55.png  867.61389  292.227    NO       728.322          865.442
```

Note that in this case, Pandas is smart enough to figure out whether you want to access a particular column (`df['filename']`) or a selection of rows (`df[selection]`). More complicated ways of accessing a dataframe are possible, but you'll have to read up on that.

You can merge some things together, and with the reading of the CSV file, it's just two lines:

```
df = pd.read_csv('datafile.csv')
df[ df['filename'] == 'AY60_52X_615f6r53d7cdc55.png' ]
```

which I think is a bit nicer than using purely NumPy. Essentially, use NumPy only when you are really dealing with (multi-dimensional) array data. Not when dealing with records / tabular structured data, as in your case. (Side note: under the hood, Pandas uses a lot of NumPy, so the speed is the same; it's largely a nicer interface with some extra functionality.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this using numpy:

```
selected_row = a[np.any(a == 'AY60_52X_615f6r53d7cdc55.png', axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
>>> selected_row
array([['LIMS_AY60_52X', 'AY60_52X_615f6r53d7cdc55.png', '867.61389', '292.227', 'NO', '728.322', '865.442']], dtype='<U32')
```